# Webdriver is not cicking a link in a inbox

Tags: webdriver, testng

My web application has an inbox, just like gmail inbox, my objective is to click on a mail item and verify the content in it.

The Outer HTML of my mail item in the Inbox is as follows

```
<a href="read_body.php?mailbox=INBOX&amp;passed_id=2&amp;startMessage=1">Complete Registration Request- My WebSite</a>
```

i wrote a java code as

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Complete Registration Request- My WebSite")).click();
```

(ps:i also tried with linkText).

another approach was

```
  @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="link=Complete Registration Request- My WebSite")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement regMailLink;
```

inside method

```
 regMailLink.click();
```

in both cases the output was as follows .

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Complete Registration Request- My WebSite"}
Command duration or timeout: 31.44 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_39'
Session ID: 2baf4e73-c070-4046-8723-b4ae430a827d
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=16.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByPartialLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:347)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByPartialLinkText.findElement(By.java:265)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at stabilix.org.hc.MailCode.testValidateEmail(MailCode.java:74)
    at stabilix.org.hc.createUserPageTest.NewUsrStage1(createUserPageTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Complete Registration Request- My WebSite"}
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_39'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/moshe/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7889540798209195994webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8251)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/moshe/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7889540798209195994webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:382)
---
---
```

Comment: Does this application contain frames?

Comment: Try to switch to the frame containing the complete registration link and then click on the link. It may work.

Comment: you are right HemChe, thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ok. This is still more thought than advice:

According your comment, that application has frames. And I think that this link will be inside frame. And this frame should have its name:

```
 <frame name="main"> //my guess
   //...
   <a href="read_body.php?mailbox=INBOX&amp;passed_id=2&amp;startMessage=1">Complete Registration Request- My WebSite</a>
   //...
 </frame>
```

So, first thing you need to do to **switch driver to this frame**

```
driver.switchTo.frame("main");
```

And then you can perform the search

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Complete Registration Request- My WebSite")).click();
```

**NOTE** The frame name is my own guess, so please do not copypaste my code. Use it as a guide ;)

Comment: thank you, you are right , switching to the frame solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here Actually we can try with the given below CSS Selector

css=a[href*='INBOX']

Please Let me know with this CSS the script is working or NOT.